# How to create a new Azure Website with integration to private Github repo using the Azure REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, kudu

There are many trivial examples that show how this is done *without* the Github integration. The Azure Powershell commandlet New-AzureWebsite supports **only** public repos (can be confirmed from source code [1]). Has anyone tried to create it with a connection to a private repo? It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

UPDATE: I've realized this might be something Kudu helps me with.

[1] https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/e06a22c22f7a1c8153e9c2fa7c159ae7b1fd1dab/src/ServiceManagement/Services/Commands.Utilities/Websites/Services/GithubClient.cs#L124

Answer (score 3):

We have not added the functionality to powershell.  However, you could try using the ARMClient tool below to achieve just that.  See its readme and wiki for info.

https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient

https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient/wiki/Setup-GitHub-publishing-to-Site

Comment: Ok, so you documented it just now, thank you. BTW, I suggest you explain the "ARM" abbreviation at some point before starting to use it. It's slightly confusing before you figure out what it stands for. I guess it's not that common abbreviation for what you use it for. At least publicly. Anyway, I'll test the tool.